# How to find the sum of numbers on a line within a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently trying to use a dictionary to accumulate the sum of all the numbers that are on the line. Each line has an ID number which is the first number on each of the lines.

It is able to ID each line, however it doesn't find the sum, it uses the second value in each line as the sum.

```
dict = {}
with open ("id_data.txt") as input_file:
  for line in input_file:
    line = line.split()
    ID = int (line[0])
    Sum = int (line[1])
    
    if ID in dict:
        dict [ID] += Sum 
    else:
        dict [ID] = Sum 
output_file = open ("id_SUMS.txt", "w")
for ID in sorted (dict):     
   output_file.write ("Line ID : " + str (ID))
   output_file.write(", Sum : " + str (dict[ID]))
   output_file.write ("\n")
output_file.close ()
print("file has been updated")
```

If anyone can help me identify where my program is going wrong and how to fix it, to where it finds the sum of the numbers on the specific line, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? When you print `dict.get([ID,0)` before and after the conditional is it changing? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like stepping through execution, setting breakpoints, and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: 1. Please refrain from using `dict` as a var name. 2. Avoid checking a key is in the dictionary just to increase its value: use [defaultdict(int)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum should be:

```
Sum = sum(int(i) for i in line[1:])
```

Comment: No need to make a list, `sum` will consume a generator expression. `sum(int(i) for i in line[1:])`

Comment: And no need to make a slice (i.e. a copy) of the line either: `lin=iter(line.split()); next(lin); s=sum(int(i) for i in lin)`

Comment: @Pynchia Does slicing really creates a copy? Can you please tell me where i can read about it.

Comment: >Shallow copies of dictionaries can be made using dict.copy(), and of lists by assigning a slice of the entire list, for example, copied_list = original_list[:]. From the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/copy.html). Many other results if you search. Experiment with the ids of the objects

Comment: The slice is a new object which is a shallow copy

Comment: @Pynchia But if I am correct it doesn't take any memory space. So it doesn't do any harm in creating a shallow copy.

Comment: Forget it. Live in bliss